# Error 405 Method not allowed .net core 2.2 mvc

Tags: jquery, .net, .net-core, model-view-controller

Hello everybody first of all I know .net core 2.2 is obselete. However the project still needs to be fixed in this version. This project has been coded with MVC pattern. The trouble I am having is this "405 error method not allowed". I'm a rookie when it comes to web development and I know a few stuff, I do want to understand why is this happening. Initially the view was supposed to send some regular data fields and five files to the webmethod of "post" request type. The web method arguments, for the files, were optional. Jquery was implemented through the submit event to send the data form and files to the post method. However it would end up with the "405 error: method not allowed". I decided to try different aproaches to test and figure out what is happening, so far nothing; we still get the 405 error. There are other cshtml file working using this algorithm, and I do not understand why is this happening. There is a singularity with this view, instead of using a model it is using a different class called a DTO (Data Table Object, I believe), since this is the front-end application none of the modules actually are within the dbcontext, because the data is retreived by calling backend methods and then transforming that data into the model's structure. Why is this method invoked this way, it has to do with some of the validations and the requirements on how to display them. That is why I need to understand what is raising the error.

Here is the webmethod:

```
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost("[action]")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<ApplicationUser>> RegisterUser(RegisterUserDTO UsuarioDTO)
        {
            bunch of code lines
            return Ok();
        }
```

the javascript method:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {
            $("#FrmData").submit(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var dataObject = {
                   some lines
                };
                $.ajax({
                    //url: '/RegistraUsuario',
                    url: '@Url.Action("RegisterUser", "RegisterUser")',
                    method: 'post',
                    datatype: "json",
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    //contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    async: false,
                    data: JSON.stringify(dataObject),
                    success: function (result) {
                        swal({
                        title: "Usuario",
                        text: "Registrado con éxito",
                        type: "success"
                        },
                        function () {
                            window.location.href = "@Url.Action("RegisterUser", "RegisterUser")";
                        });

                    },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    swal("Error", XMLHttpRequest.responseText, "error")
                }
                })
                // Se ejecuta si todo fue bien.
                .done(function (result) {
                    if (result != null) {
                        //alert("Bien");
                    }
                    else {
                        //alert("Mal");
                    }
                })
                // Se ejecuta si se produjo un error.
                .fail(function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    swal("Error", XMLHttpRequest.responseText, "error")
                })
                // Hacer algo siempre, haya sido exitosa o no.
                .always(function () {

                });
            });
        });

</script>
```

Comment: Are you sure it's using the correct URL? What is the name of the controller here?

Comment: The name of the controller is RegisterUser, there are two two methods named RegisterUser as well, one method is a Get type, the other is a Post type. I did change the name of the post method and the result was the same.

Comment: What puzzles me is that the 'get' method works just fine. Would there be any missing libraries to be reference by the controller class.